# kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget. Error

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to add these two screens to the screenmanager but i'm getting this error. What am i doing wrong? I know there are other ways to use the screen manager but i want to know how i could use it with the builder method with these seperate kv files.

**The codes that i wrote for the screens:**

Python

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class Screen2(Screen):
    def buttFunc2(self):
        print("Screen2")
```

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class Screen1(Screen):
    def buttFunc(self):
        print("Screen1")
```

KV

```
<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_release: root.buttFunc2()
        Button:
            text: "Go To Screen1"
            #on_release: i also want this function to change the screen to the other one
```

```
<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_release: root.buttFunc()
        
        Button:
            text: "Go To Screen2"
            #on_release: i also want this function to change the screen to the other one
```

**Main.py Python file:**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from screen1 import Screen1


class MyApplication(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 300,600
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("screen1.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("screen1.kv"))

        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApplication().run()
```

I also would like to go between screens by a button but i dont't know how to do it using these files.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here `Builder.load_file("screen1.kv")` will return `None`. You need to return (and add) a `Widget` instance.

Comment: Could you please explain how i could do that? Do i need to import the python files for each screen and add them as a widget instead? I'm a beginner so i didn't really understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Need to import custom `Screen` classes just like other scripts:*

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from sc1 import Screen1
from sc2 import Screen2
class MyApplication(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = 300, 600
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1())
        sm.add_widget(Screen2())
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApplication().run()
```

**sc1.py:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
class Screen1(Screen):
    Builder.load_file('screen1.kv')
    def buttFunc(self):
        print("Screen1")
```

**sc2.py:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
class Screen2(Screen):
    Builder.load_file('screen2.kv')
    def buttFunc2(self):
        print("Screen2")
```

**screen1.kv:**

```
<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_release: root.buttFunc()

        Button:
            text: "Go To Screen2"
            on_release: app.get_running_app().root.current = 'screen2'
```

**screen2.kv:**

```
<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_release: root.buttFunc2()
        Button:
            text: "Go To Screen1"
            on_release: app.get_running_app().root.current = 'screen1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to work fine but i wonder if we could keep the classes for the screens in seperate python files; because, i want to add many functions on every screen and writing them all on main.py would make it too long and overwhelming to find.

Comment: I edited my answer check it out please.

Comment: After the edit it works just fine and just as how iwanted it to ,thanks. But i don't really understand the reason why we need to use the builder method in the python files for the screens. Isn't kivy supposed to understand that those kv files that contain the same class inside them are related to that file? For instance, when i made a single screen with lots of custom widgets, i used builder only to load the kv files to the main file. It didn't require me to load the kv files into each class that i made on different python files, it understood that they were related.

Comment: All i know there are a 3 methods to call .kv file. [Load File](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_file),[Load String](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_string) and Auto App class name call. But if you need to call many files in one call, you need to create your own script which searchs and calls your widget's class name. If is there any different easy way to do that i hope someone help us so we can learn.